# Is there any truth to the rumor that Speaker for the Dead was ghost-written by a committee of Mormons for theological purposes?

Tags: enders-game, religion, orson-scott-card

I've heard and read from more than one source that Speaker for the Dead is an allegory of Hitler and his crimes against humanity and the Mormon doctrine that claims even sins so great as those are, in theory, forgivable. The rumor all strongly insinuates that Orson Scott Card may not even have written either Ender's Game, Speaker for the Dead, or both.

Is there any real evidence for such a claim? I want to avoid speculation, but if anyone knows of any inconsistencies in the works in question or interviews that OSC has given on the subject that might corroborate such an extraordinary theory I'd like to hear about it. I don't consider further rumors or hearsay to be acceptable answers.

[edit]

Having received advice from other users, I will include a link to an article that gives some weight to the theory: [Kuro5hin, 2005](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2005/5/28/22428/7034)

This link refers to several other works that say similar things. However, there is another source out there floating around that I can't seem to link to. Sorry about that.

Please note that this link is incendiary and I don't offer it to solicit flamebaiting or trolling. At least one well-known science fiction author shows up in the thread to argue with the original submitter, and it gets rather nasty.

Comment: [Related meta discussion.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2452/)

Comment: As of 6/18/2019 the link provided http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2005/5/28/22428/7034 is dead.

Answer (score 15):

The Hitler claim goes back further than *Speaker*, back to *Ender's Game*, in fact; see "Ender and Hitler: Sympathy for the Superman" by Elaine Radford.

Mr Card himself published a rebuttal to this claim in the same magazine as Ms Radford: Orson Scott Card, “Response”, *Fantasy Review* 102 (1987) pp. 13-14, 49-52 [evidently not available online]. However in John Kessel's ["Creating the Innocent Killer: *Ender's Game*, Intention, and Morality](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~tenshi/Killer_000.htm)" we find a good summary:

> Card, in the same issue of *Fantasy Review,* denied Radford’s
>   assertions.  He said that he had no knowledge of any of the Hitler
>   biographical information that Radford cited.  Such parallels were
>   “trivial coincidences.”  He said he intended Ender as the moral
>   opposite to Hitler:  Hitler knew what he was doing; Ender did not. 
>   Hitler intended to exterminate; Ender did not.  Hitler felt no moral
>   qualm; Ender spends the rest of his life expiating the guilt he feels
>   for exterminating the buggers.
>
> Let me say very clearly that I do not believe that Orson Scott Card wrote *Ender’s Game* as an apologia for Hitler.  I do not believe
>   the biographical parallels Radford finds to Hitler are evidence that
>   Card intended any parallel with Hitler—other than the parallel that
>   they both commit genocide. Like Card, I take the other points of
>   similarity as coincidences.

This is all [referenced in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game) and so isn't exactly a secret rumor.

*As for the "written by a committee of Mormons"...really? Unless one person constitutes a committee, it was not written by any such cabal. I think that there is voluminous evidence that Mr Card writes his own books and any claim he doesn't would need extremely strong evidence to even be worth researching.*